# create multiple uberjars in leiningen

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I want to create a number of uberjars with different `main` entrypoints from a single codebase.  I see you can specify the `main` namespace as an argument to `lein uberjar` but I don't see a way to specify the resulting filename or path, so they'll just overwrite one another.  Is there a way to override the output filename or path from the command line?

Or is there a better way of doing this?  Have separate project files that all reference a central "library" project?  If so, what would the physical structure of this look like and how to get it to build?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use multiple [Leiningen profiles](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md#merging) to accomplish what you are talking about.

```
(defproject project1 "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Something Amazing!"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]]
  :profiles {:v1 {:main project1.core1
                  :uberjar-name "uberjar1.jar"}
             :v2 {:main project1.core2
                  :uberjar-name "uberjar2.jar"}
             :v3 {:main project1.core3
                  :uberjar-name "uberjar3.jar"}})
```

And, you can build them with:

```
$ lein with-profile v1:v2:v3 uberjar
```

Comment: I'm noticing that the resulting jar filename isn't modified by the `:uberjar-name` option. Looks like `:name` has to be set in the profile instead in order to produce different named jar files.

Comment: There is an issue with Leiningen 2.5.0 around it ignoring the `:uberjar-name` inside profiles. It is scheduled to be resolved with Leiningen 2.5.2. https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1718

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [annotated reference](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/f50add4f90525ac8d45b32a243961970b3d4b24a/sample.project.clj#L399-L404) source where you can find an option for specifying a name of your output jar or uberjar file and any other options that may be set in a **project.clj** file.

```
;;; Jar Output
;; Name of the jar file produced. Will be placed inside :target-path.
;; Including %s will splice the project version into the filename.
:jar-name "sample.jar"
;; As above, but for uberjar.
:uberjar-name "sample-standalone.jar"
```